# Flow past square cylinder benchmark in 2D. Famous papers to compare

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-request, benchmarking, lattice-boltzmann-methods

I'm looking for a benchmark for the flow past square cylinder problem in 2D to compare my results. I have found some papers, but it seems that there are different results in different papers. I want to see the streamline and drag coefficient and lift coefficient . So do you know a famous paper which could be seen as a benchmark for others?

Comment: Have you look for it in [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=flow+square+cylinder&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C15&as_sdtp=&oq=flow+square)?  What about [this](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0363%2819980115%2926:1%3C39::AID-FLD623%3E3.0.CO;2-P/full)?

Comment: The very first result when googling "flow past cylinder benchmark": https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~maury/paps/NUM_NS.BenchmarkTurek.pdf

Comment: @ChristianClason But I want to look for the benchmark about square cylinder .

Comment: @nicoguaro Sure, I had searched papers in Google Scholar. But I don't know which paper could be treated as the benchmark. Besides, there is no streamlines or accuate vorticity contours in  the paper you mentioned.

Comment: You did not mention that what you want are the contours. If that's what you want you should add it to your question. On the other hand, why do you need third benchmark?  Are you verifying a code? Maybe you can use Manufactured Solutions.

Comment: @nicoguaro Yes , I want to verify my code. what is Manufacted Solutions?

Comment: Check these [questions](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/search?q=manufactured+solutions).  The method of manufactured solutions is a method commonly used for verification of PDE solvers.

Comment: @nicoguaro LBM was used in my code. So maybe the Manufacted Solutions is uesless for my code.

Comment: Why? The method used should not matter. Why do you say that is not possible? And why taking data from a paper would be better?

Comment: @nicoguaro LBM don't use Navier-Stokes Equations, and Manufacted Solutions is used for verification of PDE solvers. But there is no PDE in LBM. I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: @Omerta -- of course the LBM solves a PDE. It may be formulated as an integrodifferential equation, but in any case there is an underlying equation that the LBM solves, and this can be used in the method of manufactured solutions.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth -- I agree with you and would like to second your point. Although MMS is less often used with LBM, it can be used quite easily as long as the right form of the source term is used. I have used it in the context of LBM for a much more complex equation than the traditional Navier-Stokes: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021999115001916

Answer (score 1):

I believe this paper by Breuer et al. which uses both the lattice Boltzmann and the finite volume method could be of interest for you. There is tremendous information therein and I have used it before as a benchmark. I am not sure if it is THE reference, but it is a good one (and cited above 300 times)

http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0142727X99000818

Answer (score 0):

This is the work and data from Turek and group

http://www.featflow.de/en/benchmarks/cfdbenchmarking/flow/dfg_benchmark2_re100.html

Comment: I see flow past a circular cylinder in that paper but not the example of flow past a square cylinder that the OP requested. Did I miss something?